# Angular 2: apply style or use html tags in double-curly braces {{ }} of interpolation

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have created one component for tooltip. Following is how my view appears:

```
<tooltip [tooltipDisplayText]="ttp.mainText" tooltipFullText="{{ttp.fieldType}} {{ttp.mainText}} {{ttp.subText}}"></tooltip>
```

I want it to appear in as follows: assuming (fieldType : Name, mainText : Shahrukh, and subText:Actor)

**Name**
Shahrukh
*Actor*

But I am confused how can I format this in brackets. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where is `tooltip` component from?

Comment: update question with tooltip component and more code.

Comment: @yurzui: tooltip is written in Angular 2.

Comment: @micronyks: code is working fine but coming on the same line & the same text style, that's why I need to apply css/html on it

Comment: can we use html tag or class with {{ }} inside tooltipFullText. e.g: **tooltipFullText="{{ttp.fieldType}} {{ttp.mainText}} {{ttp.subText}}"></tooltip>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any string in your property in use it within `innerHTML` property

```
tooltipFullText="<div><b>{{ttp.fieldType}}</b></div>{{ttp.mainText}}
                     <div><i>{{ttp.subText}}</i></div>"
```

Then in your tooltip component:

```
@Input() tooltipFullText;

<div [innerHTML]="tooltipFullText"></div>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0lih5bRmhoAGy5RJmP6x?p=preview)**